# how to append more datas to a model return in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, loops, controller

How to append some datas into a model return in laravel.

i have a model here

```
 $marketingteam = marketingteam::orderby('id','desc')->paginate(15);
```

i want to add some more fields into this array  $marketingteam

```
targetachived = 'value';
bonus = 'value';
```

this datas calculated inside the controller.
so i want to loop it the  $marketingteam data inside the controller and i want to add more datas like the fields and i have to return to view

```
return view(['marketingteams' =>$marketingteam]);
```

how can i do this in laravel

Comment: As in your want to add `targetachived` and `bonus` to each item in `$marketingteam` or just just want to have `targetachived` and `bonus` in your view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i found the answer myself

here is the code

```
 foreach ($marketingteam  as $key => $team) {
    //if you want to call another db query you can do it here and push data

    $marketingteam[$key]->totalachive = 'new value';
    $marketingteam[$key]->bonus = 'new value';
}
```

it will push these 2 entries with all your rows

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding it to the objects as you hints at, i would suggest using Eloquent [getters](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators). This is done on the model, so you can access it like so, without having to add the fields at all time.

```
$marketingteam->target_achieved;
```

I imagine how your logic could look like, to provide an example. The function should be named `get{your_attribute_name}Attribute`.

```
class MarketingTeam extends Model {
    public function getTargetAchievedAttribute() {
        return $this->team_goal < $this->sales->sum('amount');
    }
}
```